# Reduce if loops to a single line

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to reduce the below if loops in Python. Is there any efficient way?

```
if a and b:
  print("case1")
elif not a and b:
  print("case2")
elif not a:
  print("case3")
```

Comment: Those aren't if loops (which don't exists). Instead, they are if statements. Also -- what do you do in the case that `a` is `True` but `b` is `False`?

Comment: _Why_ do you want to collapse everything on to one line?

Comment: One line is no more efficient than multiple. In fact, I'd say it's worse if it screws up readability

Answer (score 1):

While I would recommend against this type of code, if this was some sort of requirement, you could technically do:

```py
a = True
b = False
{(True, True): lambda: print("case1"), (True, False): lambda: None, (False, True): lambda: print("case2"), (False, False): lambda: print("case3"),}[(a, b)]()
```

If I had a little wiggle room to improve this slightly I might do:

```py
a = True
b = False
lookup = {
    (True, True): lambda: print("case1"),
    (True, False): lambda: None,
    (False, True): lambda: print("case2"),
    (False, False): lambda: print("case3"),
}
lookup[(a, b)]()
```

However, I would personally almost certainly use something close to your original answer:

```py
a = True
b = False

if a:
    if b:
        print("case1")
else:
    if b:
        print("case2")
    else:
        print("case3")
```